# Hash with MD5 in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, hash, md5

So, I got a bit of a problem here, I got a database, a login and a registration, all in different classes, now I need to hash the password in the database and read it out again when logging in, but I don't know how to handle this, I already searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

Here is my login class

```
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

Public Class Login

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Private Sub LSend_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LSend.Click

        If Bibliothek.EntryExists(LNAME.Text, "Username") = False Then
            LNAMELBL.Text = "Name oder Passwort Falsch."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Bibliothek.EntryExists(LPW.Text, "Passwort") = False Then
            LNAMELBL.Text = "Name oder Passwort Falsch."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim UserN As String = LNAME.Text
        Session("Admin") = Bibliothek.GetValueBool(UserN, "IsAdmin")
        Session("USERNA") = Bibliothek.GetValueBool(UserN, "Username")

        Response.Redirect("/TSL/Home.aspx")
    End Sub
    Private Sub REG_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles REG.Click
        Response.Redirect("/TSL/Registrierung.aspx")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Where are you encrypting the password and where are you checking it? Can't see anything in your code which reflects your question.

Comment: maybe I miss phrased it, from what I saw so far I would have to put it into this class right? or not? I am totally confused and don't even know what to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is important to note that MD5 is no longer considered a good way to hash data you wish to protect.  See wikipedia for a discussion of the vulnerabilities.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31150288/1070452) for hashing using SHA.

---

For passwords, you'd save the *hash* of the user's PW to the DB. Because it is one-way (you cannot easily get the original value back from the hash), this prevents someone like a janitor or customer service rep from being able to see the actual passwords in the database.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Shared Function GetHash(theInput As String) As String

    Using hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create hash object

        ' Convert to byte array and get hash
        Dim dbytes As Byte() = 
             hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theInput))

        ' sb to create string from bytes
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

        ' convert byte data to hex string
        For n As Integer = 0 To dbytes.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(dbytes(n).ToString("X2"))
        Next n

        Return sBuilder.ToString()
    End Using

End Function
```

Depending on how you want to save it, rather than a using `StringBuilder` to create a hex string, you can use `Convert.ToBase64String()`:

```
Return Convert.ToBase64String(dbytes)
' MyWeakPassword hashed:
'     to hex: DB28F1BE20A407398171295DD0D191E2
'  to Base64: 2yjxviCkBzmBcSld0NGR4g==
```

Hashing should be done with `salt`.  This is data added to the hash to make the result less predictable (there are dictionaries of the hashed results of common PW such as "password"; salt changes the outcome):

```
Shared Function GetHash(theInput As String, theSalt As String) As String
...
      hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theInput & theSalt))
```

Salt should be created using the Cryptographic random number  generator as shown in the [SHA Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31150288/1070452).  Convert the salt to text (hex or Base64) then combine with the PW to get the PW hash.

---

To check/compare a user's entry, simply hash the input and compare it to the hash stored in the database, using the same Salt (which means the Salt needs to be saved):

```
 Shared Function CheckHash(hashedStr As String, newInput As String) As Boolean
    ' get the hash value of user input: 
    Dim newHash  As String = GetHash(newInput & dbSalt) 

    ' return comparison
    Return String.Compare(newHash, hashedStr, InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
 End Function
```

As written, the `GetHash` function is intended to be used from something like a CryptoTools Class.  Since it is Shared/Static the class need not be instanced:

```
  thisHash = CryptoTools.GetHash(strToHash)
```

Note:  Hashing is case sensitive, so `foobar` will result in a different hash than `FooBar` or `FOOBAR`.  To create a **case insensitive** system, convert the original string (such as a password) to lowercase before you compute the MD5 hash value to be saved, **and** do the same for the value they later enter:

```
' ToLowerInvariant allows for foreign char sets
Dim str As String = PWTextBox.Text.ToLowerInvariant

If CheckHash(dbHashedValue, str) Then
    ' okie dokie
Else
    ' failed
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

1. MD5 Convertion

> ```
> Dim [source] As String = password_text_box.text 
> Using md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
> Dim hash As String = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, source)
> ```

2, Insert Name and hash into database

3, Validation

During login take MD5 of password again 
    run sql query

> Select name,password from table where Login ='" & username & "' and
>   Password ='" & md5(user input pass) & "'

if dreader returns value , then valid login else invalid login

Answer (score 0):

```
   Private Function GetHash(strToHash As String) As String

    Dim md5Obj As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)

    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
    Dim strResult As New StringBuilder

    For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
        strResult.Append(b.ToString("x2"))
    Next

    Return strResult.ToString

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution:

```
Public Sub _Enkripsi()

    Dim _DES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim _HashMD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()

    _DES.Key = _HashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordTextBox.Text))
    _DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Dim _DESEncrypt As ICryptoTransform = _DES.CreateEncryptor()
    Dim _Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordTextBox.Text)
    _Password = Convert.ToBase64String(_DESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(_Buffer, 0, _Buffer.Length))

End Sub
```

Comment: you should describe your solution

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to MD5 Function for Visual Studio Basic 2022

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Imports System.Text


Function CovertToMD5(retVal As String) As String
    Using MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
        Return BitConverter.ToString(MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(retVal))).Replace("-", String.Empty)
    End Using
End Function
```