# I am trying to create a password safe application in VB, but i dont know how to save user data

Tags: vb.net, settings

I'm not new to programming and software development but I am new to  password safe application in VB.

I have created a password safe application where you can add and remove passwords and usernames. But of course, if you exit the application the information goes away. I know you can use the settings to save user data but it's not quite what I'm looking for, or is it?

I have heard that VB can save text and information to a text file or an xml file and retrieve it later. Is there a certain keyword or term for this that I could google and learn about, or a web link? This would be very helpful! Thanks!

P.S. If you need anymore info i would be glad to edit this post

Comment: Keywords: Database, MD5

Comment: Or even, Keywords: "VB save text file"

Comment: You have 2 questions in one which makes it kind of broad.  If you have a small amount of data, you can serialize it.  Passwords should be hashed not encrypted. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31146658/3697824) appears to show how step by step