# Managing Username and Password in windows desktop app

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-express

I have a Windows Forms application, basically a form over data application.

Written in Visual Basic.Net and using local SQL Server Express to store data. It has 4 users listed in the combobox on the welcome screen.

I have two options of managing their passwords.

1. Either to store them at `My.Settings` or
2. To create a users table in SQL Server and work with it.

What will be your advice on this?

Comment: Hash the passwords and store them in the database. This has a complete set if tools for that: [Is it safe to store usernames and passwords in the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31150288/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix. The passwords are already hashed by textbox controls. Will they 'arrive' at the database still hashed?

Comment: I suspect one of us is confused by the term "hash".  The Win TextBox has no hashing capability.

Comment: I thot its hiding the character with a symbol like #. lol.. Direct translated?

Comment: That is not hashing.  Hashing would result in something like `bbKN8wYYgoZmNaG3IsQ2DPS2ZPIOnenl6i5NwUmrGmo=` - it is a sort of one way encryption. Study the link.  As I said, that link has all the code you need to implement salting and hashing PWs.  I'll never understand why VB people seem allergic to links/other answers